# Imprimir texto dentro de html si algo coincide con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un código similar a:

```css
.competition{
  background-size: 48px;
}
.team1{
  background-image:url(https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/unique-tournament/16/image);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<img width="48" src="https://i.ibb.co/w0qg9JF/trans.png" alt="" class="img-fluid competition team1">
```

[*Ejemplo en Codepen*](https://codepen.io/slowdmelendez360/pen/oNLrObW?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=2301a78abd851ea5a29e6c884117e4078e208140-1606050149-0-ATpUGgpAprp9ysG4wT4TaOOZ_Q8roVP1skdaHNGhkcFjUnLDud-bMAH8YLtm23mOBoA2fk_0_p4Pfy1oFmwdYHaJHLu_lJ3XmOxRli_owG7scWVxSMWHmHj-Vuuz0jmrLZBhgc_6MxCwFSgJvUBNvdO5Tw85K0TRzJWQNU0rMMtjnltfETDyB543SkLy16LXggKcX9UmceHu75SNpbAgLmjhwujtd8ZXkYbPyEnr7KB7KnRoaS7DcbDmvXLzNhBIcbeVG0kl1Qs4VjM8OmIvLBiGD71fIQDlYcVlQMJOv7dfvbLZprgWCpS4iSsZGzOzdxMaEWOb-f1srsht1W6rtNKTeKjOxbcTV_RAwmcOPf6n1BkIbDsdV5jZF4g7HBjZeQ)

¿Hay alguna manera de utilizar JavaScript para que me imprima algo de texto justo debajo de la imagen?

Es decir.

Al tener: `class="img-fluid competition team1">`

Mediante la clase "team1" escribir como texto (debajo de la imagen): "Equipo 1"

Y hacerlo así para varios elementos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado hacer lo que estaba buscando.

```js
let team1 = `
<figure class="figure">
<img class="figure img-fluid competition imgTeam" width="48" src="https://i.ibb.co/w0qg9JF/trans.png" alt="">
<figcaption style="margin-bottom: -10%; margin-top: 8%; margin-right: 5px;" class="figure-caption">
Sociedad
</figcaption>
</figure>
`;

for(const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("team-1")){ele.innerHTML=(team1)}
```

```css
.competition{align-items:center;width:48px;background-size:48px;margin-top:-5px}
.imgTeam{background-image:url(https://www.sofascore.com/images/team-logo/football_2824.png);background-repeat:no-repeat}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="team-1"></span>
```

He utilizado el siguiente código para crear mi estructura HTML utilizando "figure" de Bootstrap:

```
<figure class="figure">
<img class="figure img-fluid competition imgTeam" width="48" src="https://i.ibb.co/w0qg9JF/trans.png" alt="">
<figcaption style="margin-bottom: -10%; margin-top: 8%; margin-right: 5px;" class="figure-caption">
Sociedad
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Luego he creado una variable en JavaScript en la cual he guardado mi código:

```
let team1 = `
<figure class="figure">
<img class="figure img-fluid competition imgTeam" width="48" src="https://i.ibb.co/w0qg9JF/trans.png" alt="">
<figcaption style="margin-bottom: -10%; margin-top: 8%; margin-right: 5px;" class="figure-caption">
Sociedad
</figcaption>
</figure>
`;
```

Y por último imprimo en un elemento html lo que quiero mostrar obteniendo la clase en JavaScript con el siguiente código:

```
for(const ele of document.getElementsByClassName("team-1")){ele.innerHTML=(team1)}
```

No sé si es la manera más efectiva de hacerlo, sin embargo funciona perfecto para lo que yo necesito.

Answer (score 1):

Colocar texto directamente a una etiqueta 'img' no se puede, ya que esta etiqueta es para imagen. Pero podrias agregar una logica distinta, por ejemplo todo eso colocarlo de una etiqueta 'div' y dentro colocar tu etiqueta 'img' y una etiqueta 'p'.

```html
<div> 
  <img width="48" src="https://i.ibb.co/w0qg9JF/trans.png" alt="" class="img-fluid competition team1"> 
  <p id='agregar-texto'></p>
</div>'
```

```js
if(true){
  let p = document.getElementById('agregar-texto');
  p.innerText = 'Agregar texto' //esta propiedad inserta texto a un elemento
  p.innerHTML = 'Agregar texto' //esta propiedad inserta codigo HTMl, pero tambien puedes ocuparla para insertar texto.
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es genial, sin embargo quiero saber si realmente utilizando un solo "id" o "class" dentro de un div se puede: 1. Mostrar la imagen de "team1" y justo debajo (con figure de Bootstrap) se muestre el texto que yo indique: "Agregar Texto"